# Blogdown: change CSS in the Academic theme

Tags: css, r, blogdown

I am creating a blog with `blogdown` and the academic theme, which apparently is now available [on the repo of Wowchemy](https://github.com/wowchemy/starter-academic). This repo doesn't have the same structure compared to the previous academic theme and I am a bit lost.

I would like to change some CSS components but I can't figure out how to do so. Here's what I tried so far.

#### Modify the `.css` and `.scss` files

I tried to modify the `public/css/academic.css` file and the `resources/_gen/assets/scss/scss/main.scss_6c95cc1249b26b124274204dbf970c34.content` file. In both cases, the changes are reset after `blogdown::stop_server()` and `blogdown::serve_site()`.

This is also the case when I modify both of them before running the two `blogdown` functions.

#### Create a `custom.css`

As said in the [Wowchemy documentation](https://wowchemy.com/docs/customization/#customize-style-css), I tried to put my changes in `assets/scss/custom.css` (I had to create the `scss folder as well), but apparently it does not influence the theme.

---

**Question:** How can I change some CSS parameters in the "new" Academic theme?

Comment: Could you put the css you want to change in a `htmltools::tags$style()` function or in a css code chunk in Rmd file?

Comment: I don't think so because I want to reduce the margin of the footer, but I don't have an Rmd (or md) file for the footer, it is created automatically from `params.toml` (and I don't know how)

Comment: Do you have a minimal exapmle of an Rmd file you could post along with the desired output?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Not really because this question has nothing to do with Rmd files. It is rather related to the structure of the blog but not to its content. Basically, I want to reduce the space above the footnote of the home page. Therefore, this does not depend on a Rmd file because this space is the same, whether there are contents on the home page or not.